# Carbidopa : zwitterion

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

The pKa of carbidopa is 7-8 of the base hydrazin. Is this because of the zwitter form with the acid? Why is the basicity so low? If it can form a zwitter ion wouldnt  the pKa be higher?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbidopa

Comment: Where did you find such value? Check this: http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00190